# actionscript3 how to manage memory in ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

So we have developed an app using `AIR` that runs smoothly on `android` but crashing on `iOS`. The app just has a preloader and a folder containing a bunch of precompiled `SWF` files. The user loads one of the `SWF` called `labs` files and runs it. It looks something like this:

[image: preloader]

Now, everything worked fine and all, but once a person loads a `lab`, the new lab has multiple frames and in the beginning the app runs smoothly but as the user keeps loading frames the app crashes without any errors. I used the debugger in `Adobe Flash Professional CC 2016` and there was no error, `checked logs` etc. still no luck. In the end I just used `Instruments` and looked up the memory usage. Apparently as frames loaded the application used up all the memory and in the end crashed. The `Activity Monitor` looked really nasty :

[image: activity monitor]

now my question is, is there a specific method to manage memory in `actionscript3` from adobe's side?

Comment: If your loaded .swf files contain ActionScript code they won't work on iOS, no matter what you do. It is an imposed limitation by Apple to avoid loading external bytecode.

Comment: @MR.Phantom - I thought that too and in the beginning I had that issue where iOS limitation wouldn't let it work. But after some working around its working fine now. The only problem I am having is memory issue being capped out.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Try using Adobe Scout to profile your app. And also try with simpler .swf files until you notice which kind of code is leaking. When I want to recover memory I first set my unused objects to null and then call System.gc();

Comment: @Mr.Phantom - I think apple does not allow gc to be used in production, I tried that already.